# Web Application with static reports

Tags: web-applications, report, reporting, business-intelligence

I have a web application with login/password authentication and my clients need some reports to make decisions.
Ive been always asked about some reports that my application dont have and I have to manually programming these ones.

The perfect solution to me is to delivery a BI tool to my client (with basics reports developed for me) and, eventually, offer some trainings to handle with this tool.

My question is:
How, you developers, handle with this problem? Share your knowledge.

Tks

Answer (score 1):

Usually we program it... using any built in reporting technology o any reporting techonology from a third party, if better and available; as you don't mention any specific technology or application, we can't help you to narrow this, but if your needs are only reports that come from a SQL query, then doing it from scratch could be an overkill and using an existing reporting solution is the best way to go, for this purpose i recommend you to look at [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), which have a nice graphical query builder and can create reports by pure drag and drop, also, as you mention your system already have a log in system, you can integrate it with DBxtra's log in system in the following way: http://www.dbxtra.com/support/?p=129.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Today my web app is completely delevoped in Classic ASP and I aways have to go to Visual Studio, File, New to buld a new report.
Maybe I can split my clients in Cube (Analise Reports) and give access to this cube with the DBxtra.

Comment: Given that DBxtra uses ASP.NET, your integrations have to be loosely coupled, so splitting your application and it's reporting it's a good idea, anyway, if you want to, you can use Web Report Widgets (http://www.dbxtra.com/help-file/web_report_widget.htm) to embbed your reports into your application, and it works no matter if you use Classic ASP, PHP, or something else.